Render color separation/spot colors preview in MuPDF C Api
Asking for any help in making a kind of color separations/spot color preview using MuPDF C API.
Generally, the purpose is to allow users to choose any component (or multiple ones) and render an image like Illustrator or Indesign does:

I can read a list of spot colors using fz_page_separations(), but altering it when passing to fz_new_pixmap_from_page_with_separations() does nothing, I'm still getting a completely rendered page using processed colors and overprints. So I see no way to include or exclude arbitrary component or a color from rendering.
Would be grateful for any help.
Thank you.

Thank you, @KJ. I believe MuPDF provides a legal high-level approach to render color separations.  Their API reference, unfortunately, is brief and provides no detailed explanations of many of the aspects of their API...
